# Can't run PHP code in retrieving data from MSSQL database

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have this simple program that stores and retrieve files from the database, I can run the insertion of files but I can't seem to run the code fir retrieving the files.

I am using MSSQL for my database

Here is the code for the test connection (process1.php):

```
<?php

class Connection {

    public $conn;

    public function connectDatabase() {
        $serverName = "localhost"; 
        $uid = "sa";   
        $pwd = "joseph04";  
        $databaseName = "Profile"; 

        $connectionInfo = array( "UID"=>$uid, "PWD"=>$pwd, "Database"=>$databaseName); 

        // Connect using SQL Server Authentication 


        $this->conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);  

        // Test Connection
        if( $this->conn === false )
        {
            echo "Connection could not be established.\n";
            die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
        }
    }
}

?>
```

and here is the code for retrieving data in the database (ShowProcess.php):

```
<?php

include_once("process1.php");

class showData extends Connection {
  public function doShowData(){
    //declare the SQL statement that will query the database
         $query = "SELECT col1, col2 ";
         $query .= "FROM dbo.ProfileTable ";

    //execute the SQL query and return records
         $result = sqlsrv_query($this->conn, $query)
             or die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));

    //Show results in table

    $o = '<table id="myTable">
            <thead>
            <tr>
            <th>Col 1</th>
            <th>Col 2</th>
            </tr>
            </thead><tbody>';

          while ( $record = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result) )
              {
                  $o .= '<tr><td>'.$record ['col1'].'</td><td>'.$record ['col2'].'</td></tr>';
              }               

          $o .= '</tbody></table>';

          echo $o;



        //Show result from sql table separated by comma (commented out)
           /* while ( $record = mssql_fetch_array($result) )
            {
                echo $record["col1"] . " , " . $record["col2"] . "<br />";
            } */

        //free result set memory
            sqlsrv_free_stmt($result);

        //close the connection
            sqlsrv_close($this->conn);
  }
}

if (isset($_POST['formView'])){ 
  $i = new showData;
  $i->connectDatabase();
  $i->doShowData();
}

?>
```

and here's my error code:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 42S22 [SQLSTATE] => 42S22 [1] => 207 [code] => 207 [2] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'col1'. [message] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'col1'. ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 42S22 [SQLSTATE] => 42S22 [1] => 207 [code] => 207 [2] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'col2'. [message] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'col2'. ) )
```

I think I have messed up with the `sqlsrv_query()` parameter

please help? I'm just a newbie in PHP and MSSQL.
thanks!

also I git the code from @klcant .. mind if I use your code? thanks!

Comment: check column name or just  $query = "SELECT col1, col2 "; replace with $query = "SELECT * "; just for debugging purpose

Comment: When I change it with * there is an error message pointing to the `$o .= '<tr><td>'.$record ['col1'].'</td><td>'.$record ['col2'].'</td></tr>';` in the while loop

Comment: comment this line in while loop $o .= '<tr><td>'.$record ['col1'].'</td><td>'.$record ['col2'].'</td></tr>'; and use print_r($record) ; just to see what it is giving

Comment: @Abhishek look at the bottom for the output when I've altered my code with what you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

@Abhishek here is the output:

Okay I've done that and this is the output:

Array ( [0] => [Name] => [1] => 0 [Age] => 0 [2] => [Sex] => ) Array ( [0] => Cayas [Name] => Cayas [1] => 35 [Age] => 35 [2] => female [Sex] => female ) Array ( [0] => Celina [Name] => Celina [1] => 19 [Age] => 19 [2] => Female [Sex] => Female ) Array ( [0] => Chala [Name] => Chala [1] => 90 [Age] => 90 [2] => Female [Sex] => Female ) Array ( [0] => Inna [Name] => Inna [1] => 19 [Age] => 19 [2] => female [Sex] => female ) Array ( [0] => Jenina [Name] => Jenina [1] => 19 [Age] => 19 [2] => Female [Sex] => Female ) Array ( [0] => John [Name] => John [1] => 12 [Age] => 12 [2] => male [Sex] => male ) Array ( [0] => Joseph [Name] => Joseph [1] => 19 [Age] => 19 [2] => Male [Sex] => Male ) Array ( [0] => Lady [Name] => Lady [1] => 0 [Age] => 0 [2] => female [Sex] => female ) Array ( [0] => Mary [Name] => Mary [1] => 28 [Age] => 28 [2] => female [Sex] => female )
Col 1   Col 2

Comment: So now in your database there is no field naming col1 or col2 first thing to note , Now which fields you want to display ? (Age, Name , Sex) or all ? Let me know.

Comment: all of them if possible :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok now you use this code , it may solve your problem --

```
public function doShowData(){
    //declare the SQL statement that will query the database
         $query = "SELECT * ";
         $query .= "FROM dbo.ProfileTable ";
//execute the SQL query and return records
     $result = sqlsrv_query($this->conn, $query)
         or die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));

//Show results in table

$o = '<table id="myTable">
        <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age </th>
         <th>Sex</th>
        </tr>
        </thead><tbody>';

      while ( $record = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result) )
          {

              $o .= '<tr><td>'.$record ['Name'].'</td><td>'.$record ['Age'].'</td><td>'.$record ['Sex'].'</td></tr>';
          }               

      $o .= '</tbody></table>';

      echo $o;



    //Show result from sql table separated by comma (commented out)
       /* while ( $record = mssql_fetch_array($result) )
        {
            echo $record["col1"] . " , " . $record["col2"] . "<br />";
        } */

    //free result set memory
        sqlsrv_free_stmt($result);

    //close the connection
        sqlsrv_close($this->conn);


}
```